# LXDE keybind "Raise" window not working

Tags: shortcut-keys, window, lxde

I am using LXDE* over Ubuntu Oneiric on a DELL Studio-XPS 64-bit machine and I can't get the keybind for raising windows to work.

In my `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` I put:

```
<!-- Iconify window: it works. -->
<keybind key="A-Down">
    <action name="Iconify"/>
</keybind>
<!-- Raise window: does nothing. -->
<keybind key="A-Up">
    <action name="Focus"/>
    <action name="Raise"/>
</keybind>
```

then I `openbox --reconfigure`, but no rasing windows keybindings.
I could use the `NextWindow` action, but... not really the same.

References:

- [http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aBindings)
- [http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aActions)

<sub>*Nested question: how to know the version of installed LXDE?</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Given that keyboard events do not have a point in space, so do not have a target window, there is no window to focus and raise (the current window is already focused and raised).

If not used for a global key binding, the key event is sent to the currently active/focused window.

For the latter, `apt-cache policy lxde-core`.

Comment: Thanks @enzotib. So, after iconifying a window, does it lose the focus? And, how can I raise a window then?

Comment: @Campa: yes, it lose focus, and there is no action to restore an iconified windows (raise has another meaning: "raises a window above other windows in its layer"). After all, how can the WM know which window you want to restore?

Comment: Ok but, what does `NextWindow` action do to raise windows then? Where does the focus go? Desktop?

Comment: @Campa: it is not a window action, but a global action, the window are kept in a list, and the next to the current window is given focus.